# Trouble with Legend Position/Titles in Multi-Plot Figure (Base R)

Tags: r, plot, legend, title

I'm very new to R and I cant seem to figure out how to get the legend and titles of my multi-plot figure to get them where I want to be. I would appreciate any feedback. I researched the web and can't seem to find anything that works.

Attached is my code:

```
pacman::p_load("tidyverse", "Cairo")

parameter_results <- readRDS("param_results_2014.RDS")
pie_chart <- function(parameter, title = parameter) {
  parameter_df <- parameter_results %>%
    select(results = parameter) %>%  #keep only column for the parameter you want to plot
    filter(results != "Not Applicable") %>% 
    count(results) %>%               #
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n), perc = paste0(round(prop * 100),"%"))
  color_code <- c("Attaining" = "#99FF99", "Insufficient Information" =  "#FFFF99", "Non Attaining" =  "#FF9999")

  parameter_df <- parameter_results %>%
    select(results = parameter) %>%  #keep only column for the parameter you want to plot
    filter(results != "Not Applicable") %>% 
    count(results) %>%               #
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n), perc = paste0(round(prop * 100),"%"))

  values <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(parameter_df))
  labs <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(parameter_df))
  colors <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(parameter_df))
  for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(parameter_df))) {
    values[[i]] <- parameter_df$prop[[i]] * 100
    labs[[i]] <- parameter_df$perc[i]
    colors[[i]] <- color_code[[parameter_df$results[[i]]]]
  }

  pie(x = values, labels = labs, col = colors, main = title,font=2,font.main=2)
  mtext("Figure 2.10:Assessment Results for Key Parameters Associated with Water Supply Use,\nPercent(%) of 826 AUs", side = 3, line = -4, outer = TRUE,font=2)
  }

CairoPDF(file = "multiple_pie_plot_example", width = 11.5, height = 11) # <--- you probably will need to change the height and width.

m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
              4,5,6,
              7,7,7), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat = m, heights = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.1))  

par(mar = c(1,1,1,1))
pie_chart("Arsenic-HH", "Arsenic,Human Health")
pie_chart("Total Dissolved Solids","TDS")
pie_chart("Lead-HH - DWS", "Lead,Human Health")
pie_chart("Mercury-HH", "Mercury,Human Health")
pie_chart("DO Trout", " Nitrate")
plot.new() 
legend(x = "bottom",inset = 0,legend = c("Attaining","Insufficient Information","Non Attaining"), fill = c("#99FF99", "#FFFF99", "#FF9999"),border="#000000")
plot.new() 
dev.off()
```

This is the plot I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually reproduce your data since I don't have access to the RDS file, but I would take a close look at par (`?par`).  To get the "Figure 2.10" information on the outside, you should set "oma", that is:

```
par(oma = c(bottom, left, top, right))
```

which will let you add a border outside all your inner plots.  You'll need to figure out appropriate numbers for all 4 spots.  There is a picture in the par help which illustrates what it's doing (the defaults are 0).

Once you have space at the top, you can put something there with `title` - select `outer = TRUE` to get it in the area (instead of mtext).

```
title("Figure 2.10:Assessment Results for Key Parameters Associated with Water Supply Use,\nPercent(%) of 826 AUs", side = 3, line = -4, outer = TRUE,font=2, outer = TRUE)
```

To fix your legend, add the following to your legend:

```
legend( ## previous stuff
  x = "bottom",inset = 0,legend = c("Attaining","Insufficient Information","Non Attaining"), fill = c("#99FF99", "#FFFF99", "#FF9999"),border="#000000",
  ## new stuff:
  horiz = TRUE, # switch to column format instead of rows
  cex = 1.1, # scaling factor for text (it might make things bigger, I'd play with it)
  bty = "n"  # removes the box around the legend.  
)
```

You might need to play with a few things there if the legend is too small.  (When my numbers and legends are too small, I usually just make pdf smaller.  I have no idea if it's considered a hack or not, but it usually works!)

**To move the individual titles:**

The margin space is measured in lines.  If I remember correctly, the titles are placed on the 3rd line away from the plot.  You can "fix" this two ways (and I would try both).  First, you can manually adjust the limits of your plots to ensure that there isn't too much extra space above and below the circles.  Then, you can change which line you put the text on.  This is done by calling title() with your individual title.   Here, you have to specifically tell it NOT to put the titles in the outer margin.  For the each plot, you would call

```
title(your_individual_title, line = 1, outer = FALSE)
```

You can play with the line until you have your spacing the way you want it.

**To change the legend position:**

Your legend is in the same spot because you are calling plot.new(), which creates a blank plot. You are then adding the legend to the blank plot. To get the legend where you want it, create space in the bottom outer margin, then call legend with the option xpd = NA. This controls the limits on where the legend can be placed. Try making the inset negative (you'll need to play with this to get it right) to place the legend where you want it.

The final code should look something like this (actual numbers may vary):

```
 pie_chart <- function(parameter, title = parameter) {
  parameter_df <- parameter_results %>%
    select(results = parameter) %>%  #keep only column for the parameter you want to plot
    filter(results != "Not Applicable") %>% 
    count(results) %>%               #
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n), perc = paste0(round(prop * 100),"%"))
  color_code <- c("Attaining" = "#99FF99", "Insufficient Information" = "#FFFF99", "Non Attaining" =  "#FF9999")

  parameter_df <- parameter_results %>%
    select(results = parameter) %>%  #keep only column for the parameter you want to plot
    filter(results != "Not Applicable") %>% 
    count(results) %>%               #
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n), perc = paste0(round(prop * 100),"%"))

  values <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(parameter_df))
   labs <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(parameter_df))
   colors <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(parameter_df))
   for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(parameter_df))) {
     values[[i]] <- parameter_df$prop[[i]] * 100
     labs[[i]] <- parameter_df$perc[i]
     colors[[i]] <- color_code[[parameter_df$results[[i]]]]
   }

  pie(x = values, labels = labs, col = colors)  # It doesn't look like this has an xlim or ylim option, so you're limited here.
  title(main = title, font = 2, font.main = 2, outer = FALSE, line = 1) # move all the info relating to the titles to this command.
```

}
    CairoPDF(file = "multiple_pie_plot_example", width = 11.5, height = 11) # <--- you probably will need to change the height and width.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
              4,5,6,
              7,7,7), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat = m, heights = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.1))  

par(mar = c(1,1,1,1), oma = c(4, 0, 4, 0)) # play with oma numbers
pie_chart("Arsenic-HH", "Arsenic,Human Health")
pie_chart("Total Dissolved Solids","TDS")
pie_chart("Lead-HH - DWS", "Lead,Human Health")
pie_chart("Mercury-HH", "Mercury,Human Health")
pie_chart("DO Trout", " Nitrate")
plot.new() 
legend(x = "bottom",inset = 0,legend = c("Attaining","Insufficient Information","Non Attaining"), fill = c("#99FF99", "#FFFF99", "#FF9999"),border="#000000") 
dev.off()
```

look at the help files for these functions (title, legend, par, and pie).  You might find more options there to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to move the individual titles for each plot? That's the main problem I'm having.

Comment: Also the legend is still in the same spot when I use the code you mentioned above @Melissa Key

Comment: Your legend is in the same spot because you are calling plot.new(), which creates a blank plot.  You are then adding the legend to the blank plot.  To get the legend where you want it, create space in the bottom outer margin, then call legend with the option ``xpd = NA``.  This controls the limits on where the legend can be placed.  Try making the inset negative (you'll need to play with this to get it right) to place the legend where you want it.

Comment: I edited the main answer with the fix for titles - it's too long for a comment.  I'll add the legend fix there too.

Comment: Your the best! Thanks ! @Melissa Key

Comment: I'm sorry lol but with the title(your_individual_title, line = 1, outer = FALSE) do I put that in my function and do title=title(your_individual_title, line = 1, outer = FALSE) @Melissa Key

Comment: No.  the call to title is a separate function you put after the call to plot.